# Having trouble reading heart rate sensor from Moto 360 - Android Wear

Tags: android, android-sensors, wear-os

Has anyone successfully read the heart rate sensor from the Moto 360?

```
mSensorManager = ((SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));
mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
```

I am getting an error that states "SensorManager﹕ sensor or listener is null"

I know the Gear Live uses a different ID other than Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE...I'm wondering if that's the case with the Moto 360.﻿

I tried a sensor value of 65538 which reports itself as a "Wellness Sensor" but that does not appear to return data either.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved this problem maybe?

Comment: The sensors API, from my experiences with it, seems incredibly flaky. Hopefully I am doing something wrong and that isn't the case, but there seems to be a distinct lack of people who have had success on this front

Comment: See also my reply on a different thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/30947209/2029699

Answer (score 1):

I am doing the same on my Moto 360 and I get the sensor and the heart rate. Did you put the permission for the body data:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS"

in your Manifest.xml?

Comment: I put uses-permission in AndroidManifest.xml, but can't get heart rate. SensorManager.getSensorList doesn't return Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE.

Comment: @kazhik I have the newest SDK and it doesn't work for me. I don't see the heart rate sensor on the list. Could you help me?

Comment: @EyesClear To create a new project may fix your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489281/how-to-access-heart-rate-sensor-in-android-wearable

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem while trying to poll the heart rate from a Moto 360, the sensor was null. Did the same as you to work out that the sensor available was the wellness sensor:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);

if (sensor == null) {
  List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
  for (Sensor sensor1 : sensors) {
    Log.i(TAG, sensor1.getName() + ": " + availableSensor.getType());
  }
}
```

65538 seemed to be the correct type to use, so I used that.

```
Wellness Passive Sensor 65538
```

A [Reddit thread I found](http://www.reddit.com/r/moto360/comments/2g9up4/any_devs_here_know_how_to_read_data_from_the/) suggested this was the correct route to go. I seemed to get readings from it, but they weren't reliable.

With a little bit more research, I discovered [an open source project](https://github.com/pocmo/SensorDashboard) that polls sensor data and displays it. This seems to only work sometimes, so I am treating the sensor APIs as unreliable and have temporarily parked my project. I'll revisit this again in a couple of months and update my answer if I believe the sensor APIs to be any more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE is actually the correct ID. I had the same issue: the sensor was null even though I had the BODY_SENSORS permission in the manifest. I fixed it by removing the app, restarting the watch and by requesting the BODY_SENSORS permission at runtime (see https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-permissions.html).
After that I got the system dialogue for the body sensor permission and I then started receiving updates from the sensor.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Along with making sure permissions are set for BODY_SENSORS in your manifest, make sure, after you install your app, that permissions are enabled:

https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6321353?hl=en

This one got me for a while...

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Moto360 and hers how I solved it.

I tried all the solutions listed - re installing the app, upgrading the SDK but it dint work for me. I included permissions for body sensors in Manifest file.  I couldn't see heart rate sensor in my list of available sensors. So I believe it was a permissions issue. API 23 onwards android uses a new permissions model.

From this link  : https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-permissions.html   It says - 
"Note: For an app to use the new permissions model, it must specify a value of 23 for both uses-sdk-element and compileSdkVersion."

I changed my gradel scripts to use both minsdk and compliledsdk as 23. Also added following to my app manifiest.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23"
            android:targetSdkVersion="23"
             />
```

And Now its working !!

Answer (score 0):

From android M you need to make sure that the user is enabling the permission at the [first time the applications runs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) OR going manually to the app permission and enable it