# How to access heart rate sensor in Android Wearable?

Tags: android, wear-os, moto-360

I am having problems accessing heart rate sensor on Moto 360.

I tried following things :

```
Sensor mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRateSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

and then implement SensorEventListener interface :

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        String TAG = "tag";
        Log.i(TAG, "--------------------------");
        Log.i(TAG, msg);
        Log.i(TAG, ""+ event.sensor.getType());
        Log.i("live","--------------");
```

And what is strange to me I do not get any messages at all (not only heart rate).

Also I tried listing all sensors and it does not show Heart rate sensor on the list.

Of course I've added persmissions

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.watchtest" >

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
```

Any ideas ?

thanks.

w.

Comment: Have you tried updating the SDK? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26322757/4159941)

Comment: I agree with Kent, make sure your SDK is up to date, someone had a similar issue fixed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820771/having-trouble-reading-heart-rate-sensor-from-moto-360-android-wear#comment41398670_26322757

Comment: @Kent Is project somehow tied to the SDK? As I had latest SDK and it did not work. But when I created new project it start working.

Comment: I had same problem. I got som values for a short periode of time, then it returned the same values for a minute or so, then giving me a few different values, before it again stopped. seams like it´s a general problem for Moto 360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kent and @Murphy suggested, updated SDK was the solution. In my case I needed to drop the project and create new from scratch as even with updated SDK old one did not work.

Comment: Can you accept this answer? This way everyone knows it's been resolved.

Comment: I believe the trick is to uninstall the app from the watch. Here is a sample command:

adb -s localhost:4444 uninstall com.example.android.wearable.jumpingjack

Comment: I also have:
android:minSdkVersion="20"
android:targetSdkVersion="20"

And SDK version of watch is 4.4W.2, and in my SDK Manager it is rev.2 for SDK Platform, rev. 3 for sample, rev. 4 for Wear images and rev. 1 for sources.

Comment: With these changes, I now have Heart Rate Sensor and am able to get reading from it.

Answer (score 6):

Started to work for me after I did the following:

1. Uninstalled my app from the watch with

   ```
   adb -s localhost:4444 uninstall com.example.android.wearable.jumpingjack
   ```
2. Added permissions to get the heart rate sensor

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS"/>
   ```
3. Set the min and target SDK version to match the watch

   ```
   android:minSdkVersion="20" android:targetSdkVersion="20"
   ```

Started the app again. I received the heart rate sensor with Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE and I started to receive its readings. Although they were far from good. There were a lot of readings, but they were just the same, limited to these 5 values:

```
heartRate onSensorChanged values = [0.0], accuracy = 0, sensor = {Sensor name="Heart Rate Sensor", vendor="Motorola", version=1, type=21, maxRange=65535.0, resolution=1.0, power=0.45, minDelay=0}
heartRate onSensorChanged values = [53.0], accuracy = 2, sensor = {Sensor name="Heart Rate Sensor", vendor="Motorola", version=1, type=21, maxRange=65535.0, resolution=1.0, power=0.45, minDelay=0}
heartRate onSensorChanged values = [54.0], accuracy = 2, sensor = {Sensor name="Heart Rate Sensor", vendor="Motorola", version=1, type=21, maxRange=65535.0, resolution=1.0, power=0.45, minDelay=0}
heartRate onSensorChanged values = [55.0], accuracy = 2, sensor = {Sensor name="Heart Rate Sensor", vendor="Motorola", version=1, type=21, maxRange=65535.0, resolution=1.0, power=0.45, minDelay=0}
heartRate onSensorChanged values = [77.0], accuracy = 1, sensor = {Sensor name="Heart Rate Sensor", vendor="Motorola", version=1, type=21, maxRange=65535.0, resolution=1.0, power=0.45, minDelay=0}
```

Most of the time I was getting the same 53.0 value which doesn't seem to be my real heart rate. 77 could have been the one.

Answer (score 2):

I had quite a similar problem on the Moto 360. The sensor always returned 0.0f as a value.

Then I waited for two minutes, and suddenly values!=0 came in. It seems that this sensor needs a "warmup" before showing anything. Not really astonishing if you take into account that it measures something happening roughly once a second with the unit "beats per minute". It cannot be reliable before one or two minutes have passed. And each app has its own measurement: It doesn't matter if another heartbeat app is also running (like the Moto Body thing).

This also means that you *must* create a service to listen to the sensor (and a binder to pass the sensor's value to your activity or your phone).

Have a look at the demo project I shared on github:
https://github.com/upost/MyHeartbeat

Answer (score 0):

So, I came here, with the same problem and the simple solution is to remove the application from the watch using the adb:

```
adb -s localhost:4444 uninstall com.*packagename*
```

Then simply reinstall it using android studio,  eclipse or whatever you used originally.

Thanks to Alexander K for this solution