# Why is my wearable not listed as DataSource in Google Fit API?

Tags: android, wear-os, heartbeat, google-fit

I'm trying to access the heart rate monitor of a Samsung Gear Live watch. The watch is paired with a 4.4.4 handset and works correctly. I'm following the [official BasicSensorsApi sample](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/samples).

I can successfully connect to Google Play Services with the following scope:

```
addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))
```

But then, when I want to list all available heart rate monitors, I receive an empty list of `DataSource`:

```
private void findFitnessDataSources() {
    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mGoogleApiClient, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(
                    DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)// At least one datatype must be specified.
            .setDataSourceTypes(
                    DataSource.TYPE_RAW)// Specify whether data type is raw or derived.
            .build())
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                    for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                        if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                                && mListener == null) {
                            registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource,
                                    DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

If I change the `DataType` to, for example, `TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE` or `TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE`, the list will contain my phone, which seems logical.

Why is the watch not listed as an available `DataSource` then?

Please note:
This is not a duplicate of:

1. [Get Heart Rate from “Sensor” Samsung Gear Live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664217/get-heart-rate-from-sensor-samsung-gear-live)
2. [How to access heart rate sensor in Android Wearable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489281/how-to-access-heart-rate-sensor-in-android-wearable)

because I want to access the heart beat data through the recently released Google Fit API.

I don't think enabling debug mode on the watch is necessary, but I've tried that. Also, I don't think adding `BODY_SENSORS` permission is necessary, because the whole process is managed by Google Fit API anyway, but I've tried that too with no luck.

Comment: Hi, please, can you help me with this problem, I also have the same smartwatch but it's not visible from the app
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022431/android-how-to-get-google-fit-data-from-wearable-device

Comment: it doesn't work even if I search for all DataTypes. The devices are paired.

Comment: Hi, there are software sensors which might get it to work, see the links at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31231411/1587329 (the question in the comments above)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Samsung Gear Live watch does not advertise itself as a [BLE heart rate monitor](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/HRP.aspx) and therefore does not make the heart rate data available via the normal [Bluetooth Low Energy API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) or the Google Fit API which is built upon it.

Comment: This is truly disappointing. I've just wasted over $250 on this device. Thank you, Ian.

Comment: None of the heart rate sensors found in Android Wear devices (of today!) are truly continuous sensors such as those found on traditional heart rate monitor chest straps - those are still the best bet if you are specifically looking for accurate, near real time heart rate data.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: How about using software sensors? Should these work?

Comment: @user1587329 - do you mean writing your app that that uses the Samsung Gear Live SDK to pull information onto the phone, then registering as a software sensor with Google Fit such that you can feed that data to Google Fit? Sure, assuming the Gear SDK gives you that level of data, I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Pretty much, except for using the standard android.sensors and `android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub` APIs. See the ideas at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31231411/1587329 and concerning the watch, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664217/get-heart-rate-from-sensor-samsung-gear-live