# Android: How to get Google Fit data from Wearable device?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm following the same steps described [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors)  (the Google Fit client connection part is working fine).

```
    final DataType dataType=TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA;
    DataSourcesRequest requestData = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(dataType)  // At least one datatype must be specified.
            .build();
    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mClient, requestData)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + dataSourcesResult.getDataSources().size() + " sources "
                            + dataSourcesResult.getStatus().toString());
                    for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Data source found: " + dataSource.toString());
                        Log.i(TAG, "Data Source type: " + dataSource.getDataType().getName());
                    }
                }
            });
```

When I ask for data sources I get only one result which is the smartphone. If I add a listener then I really get data so it's working.

However it is also connected to an Android Wear smartwatch Gear Live with Android Wear app on the phone. Google Fit is installed in both of them but I'd like to get data from the smartwatch.

In the official guide I read

> The Sensors API provides access to raw sensor data streams from
>   sensors available on the Android device and from sensors available in
>   **companion devices, such as wearables**.

This code is running on the smartphone so I think it would be right to expect data sources from companion smartwatch too. But it's like invisible to my phone application. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final static String TAG = "main_mobile";
private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;
private final static String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss";
private static final String AUTH_PENDING = "auth_state_pending";
private boolean authInProgress = false;

private GoogleApiClient mClient = null;
private final static DataType dataType = TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        authInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AUTH_PENDING);
    }
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(connectionFailCallbacks)
            .build();
}

private void initFitness() {
    DataSourcesRequest requestData = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(dataType)
            .build();
    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mClient, requestData)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + dataSourcesResult.getDataSources().size() + " sources " + dataSourcesResult.getStatus().toString());
                    for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "\nData source found: \n\t" + dataSource.toString() + "\n\tType: " + dataSource.getDataType().getName());
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG, "Connecting...");
    mClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mClient.isConnected()) {
        mClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(AUTH_PENDING, authInProgress);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH) {
        authInProgress = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
            if (!mClient.isConnecting() && !mClient.isConnected()) {
                mClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}

GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks connectionCallbacks = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
        // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
        // Put application specific code here.
        initFitness();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
        // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
        if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
        } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
        }
    }
};

GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener connectionFailCallbacks = new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
    // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Cause: " + result.toString());
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            // Show the localized error dialog
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), MainActivity.this, 0).show();
            return;
        }
        // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
        // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
        // authorization dialog is displayed to the user.
        if (!authInProgress) {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to resolve failed connection");
                authInProgress = true;
                result.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_OAUTH);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
            }
        }
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you need something running on the watch side? Also I am a bit confused when you say that if you add a listener you get data. It sounds like your program is working? Or is it getting data from the phone and not the watch? Could you please clarify so that I can help you troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I get data only by the phone. I'd like to get a list of sensor attached to Google Fit, smartphone and smartwatch. The guide says that it  shows companion devices too. If I put the same code on the watch I get the list of its sensors, nothing from the phone.

Comment: I'm reading a similar problem, but at a least he can see other sensors from companion device.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822432/why-is-my-wearable-not-listed-as-datasource-in-google-fit-api?lq=1

Comment: May you post your activity source please?

Comment: yes, I've done changes in the question above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I have not tried any of this.**

It seems as though the Samsung Gear Live Sensors are not supported out of the box, but you might be able to make it work via [software sensors](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/new-sensors):

#### Your Gear Live

As said in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26823356/1587329),

> The Samsung Gear Live watch does not advertise itself as a [BLE heart
> rate monitor](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/HRP.aspx) and therefore does not make the heart rate data
> available via the normal [Bluetooth Low Energy API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) or the Google
> Fit API which is built upon it.

#### Supported Sensors

As said in [the official docs](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/),

> Google Fit includes support for sensors on the mobile device and
> Bluetooth Low Energy sensors paired with the device. Google Fit lets
> developers implement support for other sensors and expose them as
> software sensors in Android apps. Sensors supported by Google Fit are
> available to Android apps as data source objects.

#### *Possible* Solution

It seems possible to [implement additional software sensors](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/new-sensors).

(Copied template for this is at the bottom of the post, because it is lengthy).

You would get the data on the wearable following [get-heart-rate-from-sensor-samsung-gear-live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664217/get-heart-rate-from-sensor-samsung-gear-live).

#### Template (from https://developers.google.com/fit/android/new-sensors)

Add this to your manifest file:

> ```
> <service android:name="com.example.MySensorService"
>          android:process=":sensor">
>   <intent-filter>
>     <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService"/>
>     <!-- include at least one mimeType filter for the supported data types -->
>     <data android:mimeType="vnd.google.fitness.data_type/com.google.heart_rate.bpm"/>
>   </intent-filter>
> </service>
> ```

and flesh this `Service` out:

> ```
> import com.google.android.gms.common.*;
> import com.google.android.gms.common.api.*;
> import com.google.android.gms.fitness.*;
> import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.*;
> import com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.*;
> ...
>
> public class MySensorService extends FitnessSensorService {
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate() {
>         super.onCreate();
>         // 1. Initialize your software sensor(s).
>         // 2. Create DataSource representations of your software sensor(s).
>         // 3. Initialize some data structure to keep track of a registration for each sensor.
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected List<DataSource> onFindDataSources(List<DataType> dataTypes) {
>         // 1. Find which of your software sensors provide the data types requested.
>         // 2. Return those as a list of DataSource objects.
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected boolean onRegister(FitnessSensorServiceRequest request) {
>         // 1. Determine which sensor to register with request.getDataSource().
>         // 2. If a registration for this sensor already exists, replace it with this one.
>         // 3. Keep (or update) a reference to the request object.
>         // 4. Configure your sensor according to the request parameters.
>         // 5. When the sensor has new data, deliver it to the platform by calling
>         //    request.getDispatcher().publish(List<DataPoint> dataPoints)
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected boolean onUnregister(DataSource dataSource) {
>         // 1. Configure this sensor to stop delivering data to the platform
>         // 2. Discard the reference to the registration request object
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: it's a lot of work if consider what was promised by the framework. this could be a solution... thank you

Comment: You are welcome. This looks like a special case, because the Gear Live does not implement Bluetooth Low Energy.

Comment: Probably. The person who says it's **not** working in stackoverflow.com/6864712/android-alarmmanager-not-waking-phone-up is @ianhanniballake, who is working "full time as an Android Developer Advocate at Google". That makes it three (you, the other OP and @ian...) against one.

Comment: ... a library supporting an unsupported device would probably be helpful to the community ... (hint ;-))