# Moto 360 unable to access heartbeat sensor

Tags: android, wear-os, sensors, moto-360

I was having some trouble accessing the heartbeat sensor on the Moto 360 in an Android wear project. Using the code:

```
    for (Sensor sensor : mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL)) {
        Log.e("HB Service", sensor.getName() + ": " + sensor.getType());
    }
```

I found out that the heartbeat sensor and wellness sensors both don't show up in this list. I've tried using Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE as well, but either way, registering the listener says that the sensor is null. Anyone have advice to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you put the [permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BODY_SENSORS) below for the body data in your Manifest.xml:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS"
```

Another workaround in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37398531/5832311) is:

> Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE is actually the correct ID. I had the same issue: the sensor was null even though I had the BODY_SENSORS permission in the manifest. I fixed it by removing the app, restarting the watch and by requesting the BODY_SENSORS permission at runtime (see https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-permissions.html).
>   After that I got the system dialogue for the body sensor permission and I then started receiving updates from the sensor.

Also make sure that you have the latest SDK. Hope this helps!